# Project will only build when module depenency on file system has its node_modules present

Tags: javascript, npm

I have a node module on my file system [1] which I've installed on the project I'm working on. The module is setup to have peer dependencies which the project will provide. I run the install from the project, and everything appears to go fine.

However, when I come to build the project, I get lots of errors, from files within the module, saying that various node_modules in the project don't have exported member x, y, z etc.

I can resolve this problem by going to the module on the file system and running `npm install`, then going back to the project, running `npm install` and then `npm run build` again. After that, I no longer have build errors.

Can anyone provide some insight as to what is happening here? My understanding was that, the module on the file system wouldn't need to have its own node_modules folder; it only needs to inform projects which intend to use it what its `peerDependcies` are. However, as I've said, I can only get the project to build when the `node_modules` are present within the node module on the file system.

---

#### Notes

1. If this is the correct terminology; more specifically I mean that, I have a file structure for a node module on my file system, in a directory outside of the rest of my project, which I've installed in the project on which I'm working via `npm install`. The file structure is something like this:

```
|
| - Project
  | - src
  | - package.json
  | - etc.
| - Module
  | - src
  | - package.json
  | - etc.
```